# WSO2 API Manager Mask a Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is possible generated a **mask** in services in API Manager?, similar to:

Original Services in API:

```
http://API/v1/profile
http://API/v1/account
```

With mask:

```
http://API/v1/user-profile
http://API/v1/user-account
```

My ideas are:

1. In **Publisher Page  -> Runtime Configurations** add a **Message Mediation** that deleted the **user-** of the service with mask.
2. In **API Definition**, in **Publisher Page**, edit the JSON **Swagger** in the services put some mask. This is a example whit **TAG** in Swagger:

```
 tags: 
   - "/v1/kyc-perfil"
```

[image: Example With TAG]

**Is Possible or not generated a mask in service in API Manager?**

EDIT: 
After to read the answer of Bee, works but in two or more service the request in every service is the same and diferent of the service original.

I tried to put similar this:

```
    <property name="/v1/kyc-{DYNAMIC-PARAMETER}" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')"/>
    <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/v1/{DYNAMIC-PARAMETER}" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks @Bee, edit a cuestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do option 1. Use the `REST_URL_POSTFIX` property. Try this.

Read:
    `<property name="post_fix" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')"/>`

Write: 
    `<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="new_post_fix" scope="axis2"/>`

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-Property:REST_URL_POSTFIXREST_URL_POSTFIX

Comment: In part works, if a have a one server but in two or more generated conflic interno in service